# `echo "asdf"` to a C program using pipes

Tags: c, pipe

Basically, I'm trying to implement the following:

`echo "asdf" | ./a.out`

where ./a.out simply prints out "asdf"

I know this is probably noob C stuff, but as I'm only a novice C programmer, I thought I'd ask the community.

---

Update:

OK, I got it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char str[80];
  int i;

  printf("Enter a string: ");
  fgets(str, 10, stdin);

  /* remove newline, if present */
  i = strlen(str)-1;
  if( str[ i ] == '\n') 
      str[i] = '\0';

  printf("This is your string: %s", str);

  return 0;
}
```

`echo "asdf" | ./a.out` does what I need.

Comment: so you want you program to take in the asdf input and print it out? cat is for concatenating files.

Comment: Do you mean `echo` instead of `cat`?

Comment: @0A0D, pretty much, yes... But I have to use a pipe...

Comment: probably mean echo... (sorry...)

Comment: Hi Kerrek SB - could you provide a code snippet. I can't seem to find anything online. many thanks for the reply. I think I'm getting there.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: By default, `stdin` is already open ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is coming through `stdin`.

```
$ cat stdin.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    int c;
    while (EOF != (c = fgetc (stdin)))
        putc (c, stdout);
}
$ gcc stdin.c
$ echo "foo" | ./a.out
foo
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read from the standard input file `stdin` to read the piped in contents.